# Multiple Bank Accounts on one payment gateway or merchant account

Tags: web-application, pci-dss, payment-gateway

I'm looking to use PCI compliant payment gateways such as Authorize.net or Spreedly.com in my website. However in my particular case (hotel, tour, events reservations), we will serve as an intermediary for our clients for collecting and storing Credit Card Data (which will be done by these Payment Gateways).These clients may then charge or not these credit cards in a given amount of time (mostly one-off payments). Basically what booking.com does when they allow you to make a reservation with your credit card as a guarantee.

In this regard, it is common to allow the client to access the Credit Card Data once the client decides it must charge the customer, however, I would prefer that our clients have no access to the credit card data directly. Instead they would be allowed to charge them through our system .

Is it possible that once they charge and the payment gateways processes the payment for it to be forwarded to each specific client bank account.

The problem is **that we don't want to handle receiving money and then distributing it to our clients, we want them to receive their payments into their account themselves.**

Of course, we would handle their bank account data securely through Authorize.net CIM or Spreedly's Vault service.

Finally, the question is: Is such a scheme possible? that I could redirect payments received through a gateway to different bank accounts (potentially hundreds) depending on the transaction? Mind you, I'm not asking for split payments, there is only one and only one recipient per transaction, but given the kind of thing the customer is purchasing these recipient may vary.

Sorry for the long post and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're interested in being a [PayFac](http://I%20think%20you%20want%20to%20be%20a%20[payfac](http://www.vantiv.com/Partner-with-us/Payment-Facilitators)):

- Provide payment transaction routing
- Settle to sub-merchants

And use tokenization to avoid holding card details.

I think PayFac is a Vantiv-specific term, so you may want to look at the bullet items on that page and try to match them to the processor you're using, to determine if they have an equivalent.